# What Does these symbol mean.

Tags: probability

It's very simple. I don't know how to interpret these symbols (highlighted in image below) in the context of this example.
So, can someone tell me how to read them?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glm8g.png)

Comment: e.g. $\bigcup_{j=1}^3A_j$ stands for $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3$.

Answer (score 0):

We indicate with

- $\bigcup_i A_i$ the [UNION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) of the sets $A_i$ that is 
  $$A_1\cup A_2\cup\ldots\cup A_n$$
- $\bigcap_i A_i$ the [INTERSECTION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) of the sets $A_i$ that is

$$A_1\cap A_2\cap\ldots\cap A_n$$

Comment: that was useful, thanks

Comment: @EslamMedhat You are welcome! Refer also to the given link and to the duplicate which contains more information. Bye